# Is there an equivalent of addJavascriptInterface() from Android in Windows 8?

Tags: android, windows, windows-8, webview, internet-explorer-10

My company uses Android apps built within WebViews with a little native code that is accessible via a JavaScript interface.

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "jsInt");
```

Where members of the class JavaScriptInterface are accessible through JavaScript within the WebView.

```
<script> jsInt.nativeMethodCall(); </script>
```

I'm wondering if Windows 8 has the same functionality.  If so, could someone point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not precisely the same functionality, but there is a mechanism to communicate back and forth from JavaScript to C# within a WebView.

Also keep in mind that HTML 5/JavaScript is a native development option for Windows 8, so your code might not need to run in a WebView at all. You could potentially port the application to an HTML5/JS target, and then interact with other Windows Runtime Components, which can indeed be written in C#.

That said, for the WebView, which would be hosted inside of a C#/XAML application and host HTML/JS (like in Android):

[InvokeScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescript.aspx) will allow you to invoke a JavaScript method from C# in the currently loaded WebView document

In your C# code you can listen for [ScriptNotify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.scriptnotify.aspx) events to respond to payloads passed via windows.external.notify.

Both of these are part of the [XAML Web View Control example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-WebView-control-sample-58ad63f7), and could form the basis of something a bit more like the Android functionality.

Comment: I did some digging and was able to find what I need: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779077%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: that reference is when building an app with HTML 5/JavaScript 'natively' (the option I mentioned in the preface to my answer)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a simple tutorial for this: [Creating a simple component in C# or Visual Basic and calling it from JavaScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779077%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)